# Help with multivariable functions and gradient vector.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I wanted help to find the result of a specific exercise:

Let $f(x, y, z) = x \sin(yz)$. Determine the gradient vector of $f$, and then the directional derivative of $f$ at point $(1, 3, 0)$ in the direction of $\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{i} + 2\mathbf{j} - \mathbf{k}$.

My answer:

The gradient vector of $f$ at $(1, 3, 0)$ is $(0, 0, 3)$, and then, substituting it into $D_uF$, it resulted in $3 \cdot (-1/\sqrt{6})$.

I found $D_uF(1,3,0) = -\sqrt{6}/2$. However, my professor's answer key gave $-\sqrt{3/2}$. Could I be making a mistake in something?

Comment: They are the same.  Write $-\sqrt{3/2}$ as $-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}$ and rationalize.